# .htaccess rewrite to redirect & change url in address bar

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to direct **domanin2.com** the page at **domain1.com/landing-page/** but I would like the browser to display **domanin2.com** in the url address bar.  Is there a way to do this?

So far I've tried this in my **.htaccess file**:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domanin2\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domanin2\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/domain1\.com\/landing-page\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^\.html$ /domanin2/ [L]
```

It works in so far as **domanin2.com** is redirected to **domain1.com/landing-page/** but **domain1.com/landing-page/** is also displaying in the url address bar rather than **domanin2.com**.

Is this posible, I'm trying to avoid getting a second hosting account.  I own both domains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both of your domains are on different servers or have different document roots, the only thing you can do is use mod_proxy. Most hosting services turn this off as they don't want people proxying, but if you have it turned on, replace the `R=301` with a `P`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domanin2\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domanin2\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/domain1\.com\/landing-page\/" [P,L]
RewriteRule ^\.html$ /domanin2/ [L]
```

But it won't work at all if apache doesn't have mod_proxy loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your comments on my answer, I had missed that. +1 for yours. :)